# get a session variable when clicked on link through foreach loop

Tags: php, database, session

I'm trying to get a session variable to be set when clicking on a link.
The value of the variable is generated out of a DB using PHP. I've tried everything, but noting seems to work.

There is a foreach-loop that displays usernames. Each username is a link to a second page. The username that is clicked on should become the session variable. 
The code that loops looks like this:

```
echo "<a href= 'nominate.php'> ".$myotherusers['username']. "</a><br/>";
```

goal being that when clicked on the link this code is executed:

```
$_SESSION['varname'] = $myotherusers['username'];
```

I just can't seem to be able to figure out how...
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
echo "<a href='nominate.php?user=".$myotherusers['username'].">".$myotherusers['username']."</a><br />";
```

and then in your action:

```
$_SESSION['varname'] = $_GET['user'];
```

Comment: I think the page has already been sent to the client, so this won't work.

Comment: The second line would reside at the top of nominate.php.  I think the author has total control of whether the headers are sent yet at that point.

Comment: Sorry, comprehension failure :)